# Issue with div with image as a gradient on high dpi devices

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML + CSS:

```css
.item {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/FOmRt87.jpg') no-repeat;
}
.item .gradient {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/oSpOTeK.png') repeat-x center bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="gradient">
  </div>
</div>
```

It's rendered in the browser properly. But on mobile ([see the attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhZbm.jpg)) there's a one thick line across the gradient, I have no idea why is that.

Here's also I js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tcxka242/1/

First I thought that is repeated vertically as well, but the inspector says that the rule I've set: `background: url(...) repeat-x center bottom;` is expanded to :

```
background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/oSpOTeK.png");
background-position-x: 50%;
background-position-y: 100%;
background-size: initial;
background-repeat-x: repeat;
background-repeat-y: no-repeat;
background-attachment: initial;
background-origin: initial;
background-clip: initial;
background-color: initial;
```

That's on Android Phone with Google Chrome.

Comment: Probably some subpixel issue on high density screens.

Comment: try @Dragutescu Alexandru answer, I think he did right

Comment: @BramVanroy tried creating a new image for this gradient. Same issue. Probably should export it with different settings?

Comment: I just tested the fiddle on my Surface Pro 3 (Hi DPI as well) and it has the same issue. Do you really need to use an image? You can quite easily solve this with pseudo-elements and a gradient.

Comment: @BramVanroy Yep, I was going to create the gradient with CSS, but I'm curious why this happens. :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but i cannot properly verify this , but i have an idea for you .

```
.item .gradient {
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  outline: 0;
  border: none;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/oSpOTeK.png') repeat-x center bottom;
}
```

As you can see i have set the outline to 0 and the border to none . There's a possibility that there is an outline from the div or a hidden border .

Comment: I think the same way, as the line exist at the end of the gradient part, so it is root issue

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem. That line is still there.

Comment: @IvankaTodorova why are you not using css for gradient??

Answer (score 0):

Specifying `border-top: 0px;` and `box-shadow: none;`  will work for you

```
.item .gradient {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  left: 0;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/oSpOTeK.png') repeat-x center bottom;
border-top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Nope, the problem still persist.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is caused on screens with high DPI. Therefore I am providing a CSS-only alternative.

https://jsfiddle.net/tcxka242/6/

```
.item {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/FOmRt87.jpg') no-repeat;
}

.item:after {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    pointer-events: none;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 70%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 100%);
}
```